# How can I rewrite SQL query to get one team's stats versus opponents played stats?

Tags: mysql

I have written an SQL query to display the schedule of a specific team along with their scores and 1st downs made.

```
SELECT DISTINCT

/*From statsSchedules*/
  homeScore

/*From leagueTeams*/  
, homeTeam.logoId       homeLogoId 
, homeTeam.abbrName     homeAbbrName

/*From statsTeamStats*/
, homeTeamStats.off1stDowns AS home1stDowns


/*From statsSchedules*/
, awayScore

/*From leagueTeams*/
, awayTeam.logoId       awayLogoId 
, awayTeam.abbrName     awayAbbrName

/*From statsTeamStats*/
, awayTeamStats.off1stDowns AS away1stDowns

FROM statsSchedules
INNER JOIN leagueTeams AS homeTeam 
ON statsSchedules.homeTeamId = homeTeam.TeamId


INNER JOIN statsTeamStats AS homeTeamStats
ON statsSchedules.homeTeamId=homeTeamStats.teamId
AND statsSchedules.homeTeamId=homeTeamStats.teamId 
AND statsSchedules.scheduleId=homeTeamStats.scheduleId


INNER JOIN leagueTeams AS awayTeam 
ON statsSchedules.awayTeamId = awayTeam.teamId 

INNER JOIN statsTeamStats AS awayTeamStats
ON statsSchedules.awayTeamId=awayTeamStats.teamId
AND statsSchedules.awayTeamId=awayTeamStats.teamId 
AND statsSchedules.scheduleId=awayTeamStats.scheduleId

WHERE awayTeam.abbrName LIKE 'DAL' 
AND statsSchedules.stageIndex=1 OR homeTeam.abbrName LIKE 'DAL' 
AND statsSchedules.stageIndex=1 
ORDER BY `statsSchedules`.`weekIndex` ASC
```

That query outputs this..

```
 |homeScore|homeLogoId|homeAbbrName|home1stDowns|awayScore|awayLogoId|awayAbbrName|away1stDowns|
 |   24    |    10    |    DAL     |     12     |   16    |    15    |    NYG     |      8     |
 |   10    |    3     |    DEN     |     8      |   16    |    10    |    DAL     |      11    |
 |   16    |    6     |    ARI     |     16     |   22    |    10    |    DAL     |      9     |
 |   34    |    10    |    DAL     |     12     |   13    |    23    |    LAR     |      7     |
 |   13    |    10    |    DAL     |     11     |   31    |    19    |    GB      |      8     |
```

What I would like to do now is create a new table that has DAL's total points scored and the total points scored by the opponents DAL has played.

I'd also like to have a column displaying DAL's 1stDowns and another column displaying the total number of 1st downs made by it's opponents.

Expected

```
|mainTeamPts|mainTeam1stDowns|opponentsPts|opponents1stDowns|
|   109     |      55        |    86      |      59         |
```

Comment: upadte your question and show the result you need

Comment: You are not clear about what the table you wnat looks like. Please read & act on [mcve] (as you were told in asking). What have you got so far for any of those? Read about SUM.

Comment: okay I have edited my question and added the expected. Sorry I'm still new to SQL so it's a bit hard to figure out how to ask correctly.

Comment: Good. Now please read my last comment again & address all of it. Please read [ask] & other links at [help]. Also read about SQL `group by` & `aggregate functions` including many examples. Besides not giving an [mcve] or showing any effort at your question solution, you are asking us to write a tutorial, instead of reading some. When you try to apply what you are reading ask us when you get stuck. It also seems extremely likely that you have not googled much re your question/problem/desiderata (many clear, concise specific variations, with & without your specifc table/column/appication terms).

Comment: I have googled much Philip and none of it has helped understand how it is that I'm supposed to write a query that will give me the expected. I know of the GROUP BY but I'll look up more about  aggregate functions. Thanks for the help, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 examples based on the small result table above, they might give you ideas on how to proceed.

Demonstrated here at: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9c8f/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE QryResult
    (`homeScore` int, `homeLogoId` int, `homeAbbrName` varchar(3), `home1stDowns` int, `awayScore` int, `awayLogoId` int, `awayAbbrName` varchar(3), `away1stDowns` int)
;

INSERT INTO QryResult
    (`homeScore`, `homeLogoId`, `homeAbbrName`, `home1stDowns`, `awayScore`, `awayLogoId`, `awayAbbrName`, `away1stDowns`)
VALUES
    (24, 10, 'DAL', 12, 16, 15, 'NYG', 8),
    (10, 3, 'DEN', 8, 16, 10, 'DAL', 11),
    (16, 6, 'ARI', 16, 22, 10, 'DAL', 9),
    (34, 10, 'DAL', 12, 13, 23, 'LAR', 7),
    (13, 10, 'DAL', 11, 31, 19, 'GB', 8)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
    teams.AbbrName, r1.homeScore, r1.home1stDowns, r2.awayScore, r2.away1stDowns
from (
      select homeAbbrName AbbrName from QryResult
      union
      select awayAbbrName from QryResult
     ) teams
left join (
          select homeAbbrName, sum(homeScore) homeScore, sum(home1stDowns) home1stDowns
          from QryResult
          group by homeAbbrName
          ) r1 on teams.AbbrName = homeAbbrName
left join (
          select awayAbbrName, sum(awayScore) awayScore, sum(away1stDowns) away1stDowns
          from QryResult
          group by awayAbbrName
          ) r2 on teams.AbbrName = awayAbbrName
order by teams.AbbrName, homeAbbrName
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9c8f/1/0)**:

```
| AbbrName | homeScore | home1stDowns | awayScore | away1stDowns |
|----------|-----------|--------------|-----------|--------------|
|      ARI |        16 |           16 |    (null) |       (null) |
|      DAL |        71 |           35 |        38 |           20 |
|      DEN |        10 |            8 |    (null) |       (null) |
|       GB |    (null) |       (null) |        31 |            8 |
|      LAR |    (null) |       (null) |        13 |            7 |
|      NYG |    (null) |       (null) |        16 |            8 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select
    abbrname
  , logoid
  , sum(score) score
  , sum(1stdowns) 1stdowns
from (
      select `homeScore` score, `homeLogoId` logoid, `homeAbbrName` abbrname, `home1stDowns` 1stdowns
      from QryResult
      union all
      select `awayScore`, `awayLogoId`, `awayAbbrName`, `away1stDowns`
      from QryResult
    ) d
GROUP BY
    abbrname
  , logoid
ORDER BY
    abbrname
  , logoid
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9c8f/1/1)**:

```
| abbrname | logoid | score | 1stdowns |
|----------|--------|-------|----------|
|      ARI |      6 |    16 |       16 |
|      DAL |     10 |   109 |       55 |
|      DEN |      3 |    10 |        8 |
|       GB |     19 |    31 |        8 |
|      LAR |     23 |    13 |        7 |
|      NYG |     15 |    16 |        8 |
```